# Invoking a script with ld-linux.so?

Tags: shell, scripting, libraries, dynamic-linking

I just downloaded a `tar` file that is supposed to include everything required to run a program that we can call `some_binary`. I extracted it's contents, and I see the following:

- A binary (let's call it `some_binary`)
- A `lib` folder with various dynamic libraries (.so files) such as `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so`
- and a shell script called `some_binary.sh`

The script has the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
`dirname "$0"`/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2   `dirname "$0"`/some_binary "$@"
```

and running it as `./some_binary.sh some arguments` seems to run `./some_binary` correctly. Oddly enough, running the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CWD/LIB:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./some_binary "$@"
```

as `./my_script.sh some arguments` does not work. It results in relocation errors (undefined symbols), presumably from incorrectly loading the libraries under `./lib`

Moreover, running the following two statements from the command line results in `segmentation fault`:

```
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CWD/LIB:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> ./some_binary some arguments
```

With this, my questions are:

1. What does the first script do?
2. Why do I get different results across these three attempts? and why can't I just add `$pwd/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and then run `some_binary` directly?

Comment: Is it a backslash before that second backtick?

Comment: @Sukminder. Good catch. Thanks. I had problems typing embedding the command within a code block in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program comes with its own [dynamic loader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading). It's quite rare for programs to need their own dynamic loader: usually the one on your system will work too. This may be necessary if the program was linked against a standard library other than GNU libc or if it was linked against a GNU libc compiled with strange settings.

It may be enough to tell the loader where to find the program's preferred libraries. Your attempt almost does that, but not quite. If `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not already in the environment, then the assignment `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CWD/LIB:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` only defines a shell variable, not an environment variable, so the program doesn't see a thing. Furthermore, `$CWD` usually expands to the empty string, you probably meant `$PWD` or better `$(dirname "$0")` (i.e. the directory containing the script). Also beware that you used `lib` and `LIB` inconsistently in your question. Try

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(dirname "$0")/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
exec "$(dirname "$0")/some_binary" "$@"
```

or better, to avoid having an empty entry at the end of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if it wasn't defined before (this can be bad because an empty entry stands for the current directory, though at the end of the path it's only harmful if a library isn't found where it should be):

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(dirname "$0")/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
case "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" in *:) LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH%:};; esac
exec "$(dirname "$0")/some_binary" "$@"
```

Comment: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="..."` is a BASHISM!!1

Comment: @nodakai No, there's nothing bash-specific (or even ksh/bash/zsh-specific) about it. The scripts in my answer use only POSIX features.

Comment: Hmm. I stand corrected... It seems it's been a part of POSIX for quite a while http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/export.html This guy had the same misunderstanding http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193095/where-is-export-var-value-not-available