# Where is "export var=value" not available?

Tags: shell, history, compatibility

I have picked up -- probably on Usenet in the mid-1990s (!) -- that the construct

```
export var=value
```

is a Bashism, and that the portable expression is

```
var=value
export var
```

I have been advocating this for years, but recently, somebody challenged me about it, and I really cannot find any documentation to back up what used to be a solid belief of mine.

Googling for [`"export: command not found"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22export:+command+not+found%22) does not seem to bring up any cases where somebody actually had this problem, so even if it's genuine, I guess it's not very common.

(The hits I get seem to be newbies who copy/pasted punctuation, and ended up with [`'export: command not found`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2087839) or some such, or trying to use `export` with `sudo`; and newbie `csh` users trying to use Bourne shell syntax.)

I can certainly tell that it works on OS X, and on various Linux distros, including the ones where `sh` is `dash`.

```
sh$ export var=value
sh$ echo "$var"
value
sh$ sh -c 'echo "$var"'  # see that it really is exported
value
```

In today's world, is it safe to say that `export var=value` is safe to use?

I'd like to understand what the consequences are.  If it's not portable to v7 "Bourne classic", that's hardly more than trivia.  If there are production systems where the shell really cannot cope with this syntax, that would be useful to know.

Comment: thanks I finally understood why I see so often the thing that I thought was useless: var=value;export var

Comment: There's still a few Solaris boxes kicking around, and those are notoriously frugal in their standard tools; on the other end of the spectrum, doesn't `busybox` come with its own minimal shell? (I am not in a position to try either right this second.)

Comment: Thanks Ulrich, Solaris may well be the culprit why this long syntax is still around.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
export foo=bar
```

was not supported by the Bourne shell (an old shell from the 70s from which modern `sh` implementations like ash/bash/ksh/yash/zsh derive). That was introduced by `ksh`.

In the Bourne shell, you'd do:

```
foo=bar export foo
```

or:

```
foo=bar; export foo
```

or with `set -k`:

```
export foo foo=bar
```

Now, the behaviour of:

```
export foo=bar
```

varies from shell to shell.

The problem is that assignments and simple command arguments are parsed and interpreted differently.

The `foo=bar` above is interpreted by some shells as a command argument and by others as an assignment (sometimes).

For instance,

```
a='b c'
export d=$a
```

is interpreted as:

```
'export' 'd=b' 'c'
```

with some shells (`ash`, older versions of `zsh` (in sh emulation), `yash`) and:

```
'export' 'd=b c'
```

in the others (`bash`, `ksh`).

While

```
export \d=$a
```

or

```
var=d
export $var=$a
```

would be interpreted the same in all shells (as `'export' 'd=b' 'c'`) because that backslash or dollar sign stops those shells that support it to consider those arguments as assignments.

If `export` itself is quoted or the result of some expansion (even in part), depending on the shell, it would also stop receiving the special treatment.

See [Are quotes needed for local variable assignment?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97560) for more details on that.

The Bourne syntax though:

```
d=$a; export d
```

is interpreted the same by all shells without ambiguity (`d=$a export d` would also work in the Bourne shell and POSIX compliant shells but not in recent versions of `zsh` unless in `sh` emulation).

It can get a lot worse than that. See for instance [that recent discussion about `bash`](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2014-12/msg00028.html) when arrays are involved.

(IMO, it was a mistake to introduce that *feature*).

Comment: I was surprised that the semicolon is not required in `foo=bar export foo`, as I had always seen it there. I know export is a builtin, but why does `foo=bar; foo=baz export foo; echo $foo` behave differently than `foo=bar; foo=baz /bin/cat /dev/null; echo $foo`?

Comment: @jrw32982, because it's a builtin. You still get that   in modern POSIX shells but [only for _special_ builtins](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14) which `export` is.

Comment: Although it discusses `declare`, not `export`, I recommend that anyone who cares about security read  the discussion at [the link that StéphaneChazelas provided to bash.bugs](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.bash.bugs/22737).

Comment: Great answer! But it took a long time to get to _`d=$a export d` is interpreted the same by all shells without ambiguity_ ;-)

Comment: @conny, `d=$a export d` doesn't work anymore in `zsh`, so I've updated the answer. See edit.

Comment: +1. Also, your answer suggests this but I think it would be better to be more clear at the beginning that in general `foo=bar export foo` is not portable, and teaches an even more generally un-portable habit. There are shells for which `foo=bar abuiltin` does not set `foo` as one would expect. This is the kind of portability detail I would normally ignore but if we're talking about the kind of portability where not doing `export foo=bar` matters, then this also matters.

Comment: @mtraceur, `foo=bar export foo` is Bourne and POSIX (as `export` is a so-called _special builtin_). Do you know of any shell beside `zsh` (when not in `sh` emulation, except in a few versions) where it doesn't work?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas My main point is more general, about the portability of the pattern *as humans will learn it*: most people who see `foo=bar export foo` without disclaimers will eventually try to expand it to `foo=bar some command`, which will generally seem to work right in most common uses so they will come to trust it, and then they will be bitten by portability problems when `some command` turns out to be one of the exceptions that doesn't work portably.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I *have* seen claims that `foo=bar some_builtin` is not portable to all shells for all builtins, but I don't know which builtins that was referring to. Since you can't think of any other exception for `export` specifically, and I trust you as somewhat of a domain expert in the field of shell script portability, I guess I mostly trust `foo=bar export foo` to portably put `foo` into the environment with the value `bar`, and I guess I sorta trust that all shells will then portably expand `$foo` to the same value in subsequent commands.

Answer (score 32):

It is not a bashism but a POSIX compliant syntax. It actually started as a kshism quite a long time ago and was later adopted by almost all Bourne syntax based shells. The only notorious exception is `/bin/sh` on Solaris 10 and older which sticks to the legacy Bourne shell syntax. Hopefully, Solaris 11 uses a POSIX compliant shell as `/bin/sh`.

By the way, `export` was already a builtin command in the legacy Bourne shell so googling for `export: command not found` was misleading.

Here is the legacy Bourne shell behavior when `export` is combined with an assignment:

```
$ export var=22
var=22: is not an identifier
```

For the nostalgics, the [source code of this <s>original</s> Bourne shell](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html) is available and can be compiled for most Unix and Linux distributions.

Comment: Many thanks for the historical insight and the correct error message to google for!  Obvious in retrospect, blush...

Comment: That's not the source code of the original Bourne shell, that's a modified OpenSolaris sh. It is the Bourne shell but after having undergone decades of evolution. The original Bourne shell, as shipped with Unix V7 can be found [at the Unix Heritage Society](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/sh)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Strictly speaking, you are as usual correct. Note however that I didn't wrote "the original Bourne shell" but "this original Bourne shell" as I was referring to the shell used by Solaris 10 and its source code that can be compiled on modern platforms. Note also that the Bourne shell had several features added between 1977 and 1989 but then essentially ceased to evolve (outside porting/adapting to newer platforms and bug fixes) in the last 25 years or so.

Comment: @jeffSchaller Thanks for correcting *affectation*, a false friend as it means "assignment"  in French. On the other hand, to **G**oogle is [controversial](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27193/to-google-something-capitalize-or-not)

Comment: Ahhh, I haven't learned enough French to recognize *affectation*; thanks for the background! I've also just learned about the xerox effect when it comes to verbs, so I'm happy to revert that change.